# File transfer single connection or multiple connections?

Tags: c#, multithreading, sockets, ftp, tcpclient

I developing a client/server program that allows the user to upload/download files from/to the server. Now the program works similarly to the FTP protocol: it opens two separate socket connections, one for commands and the other one for file data transfer.
The two connections are handled by the in two different threads and they work in the following way.

1st thread (commands): it sends a message BEGIN_FT nFiles to the server and starts the 2nd thread.

2nd thread (data): it sends nFiles times a message SEND_FILE fName fSize and then it starts sending the file.

The server has 2 different threads as well to handle commands and data connections.

Since the user should not be allowed to perform any other action on the client during the file transfer, would it be better to do everything using a single connection for both commands and data?

Comment: Show what you have tried so far.

Comment: So far I open a SSL connection for the command connection. When the user starts a file transfer a second SSL connection is opened to the server. When the file transfer ends, the data connection is closed.
Since I just need to send/receive some files and nothing else, I was wondering if there will be any advantages/disadvantages by using just a single connection?

Comment: How do you handle packets? Are you using length- and header-prefixing? Because if you are, you could simply use one connection and just keep reading the packets, checking if it's a file part or a command.

Comment: Inside a command message i send the filename and its size. So the server parses the received command and knows the filename and its size.

Comment: Is this specifically for FTP, or is it just something similar you've made? If it's something you've made (and you're not aiming to connect with normal FTP of course) I recommend you to to add a header to every packet containing: 4 bytes representing the packet length, 1 byte representing what type of packet this is (i.e. file part or command).

Comment: I'm programming using C#, everything should be already handled by the TcpClient and Socket classes as far as I know..